# Pattern to create SQL import scripts for multiple sources

Tags: python, design-patterns, mapping

I have a database that has a fixed set of fields, lets call them

```
field_1, field_2, field_3
```

I also have multiple different data sources that are text files that contain a superset of those fields. For instance a source might have the following fields

```
field_10, field_3, field_1, field_2, field_12
```

I am now looking for a generic way to create such a mapping (by hand) in Python. In an abstract sense this would be for example

```
Position 1 -> None
Position 2 -> field_3
Position 3 -> field_1
Position 4 -> field_2
Position 5 -> None
```

From this I could then generate a SQL COPY statement. 
I'm sure that I could hack this together, but I would prefer a solution that I can configure for every source. I don't need a finished solutions, pointers to the right pattern or idea would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
db = ["field_1" , "field_2" , "field_3"]
file = ["field_10", "field_3", "field_1" , "field_2", "field_12"]
map = [ field_i if  field_i in db else None for field_i in file ]
```

Time complexity: O(n^2)